# Listing SQL queries on Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

My concern is that Can I find all SQL queries fired on the Apache Ignite grid. Basically any logs or visualization of SQL Queries. It will be a history of all queries run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install GridGain Web Console and use Queries Monitoring screen:
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/web-console/latest/queries-history-monitoring